# What are the best authentication and authorization examples for your favorite web framework?

Tags: authentication

I have been looking through java web frameworks lately (though this question need not be limited to java), and I noticed that most examples on web framework websites leave out auth & auth examples in their stock documentation.

one ruby example: acts_as_authenticated (link?)

grails has: http://www.grails.org/Authentication+Plugin

Anyway, please throw up some links to your framework of choice, and a link to a nice walkthrough to implementing an auth&auth solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article related to stipes: http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=Stripes15